# Is there a way to parse Date from StringBuilder?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I want to parse `Date` from `StringBuilder` without conversion to `String`.

[`SimpleDataFormat.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) implementation use only `CharSequence` methods, `length()` and `charAt()`, but defined as defined.

Is there simple (standard) way to do this, except copying the whole `SimpleDateFormat` class, for example?

Comment: `I want to parse Date from StringBuilder without conversion to String.` Why?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis to avoid unnecessary garbage creation

Comment: Unless you have an extremely long date string, you really shouldn't care about creating a new `String` object from the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't want to make the method that parse many Dates one after another a steady source of garbage while it is unnecessary at all.

Comment: unless you find this actually is causing a performance issue, we call this premature optimization

Comment: Do you need to parse the `Date` before the `String` is finished building? There is no way to use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a `Date` from a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis maybe there is util for this in commons-lang or another lib? I haven't found.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23643818/648955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is [DateTimeFormatter.parse(CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method in Java 8's `java.time` package. Overlooked it.